# gvim taking so long to display 'all tags' using g ctrl-]

Tags: vim, tags

I am navigating c++ code using gvim and ctags. Size of the ctags file is 3.5 GB.
ctrl-] is working pretty quick, but g+ctrl-] is taking nearly 5 seconds, which I think is too much (that is too much time for searching a sorted ctgas file!). Any suggestions to improve  speed?

**My .gvimrc:**

```
set gcr=n-c-v:blinkoff0         " it switches off cursor blinks
set lines=52 columns=120        " Sets the geometry of gui window.
colorscheme default             " desert load the color scheme of choice
set nocompatible                " This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set ic
set backspace=indent,eol,start  " allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set history=10000               " keep 100 lines of command line history
set showcmd                     " display incomplete commands
set incsearch                   " do incremental searching
set et
set paste
set ruler
```

Comment: Any reason why ic is a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have `'ignorecase'` on, Vim mostly needs to perform a linear search of the tags database, instead of a much faster binary search. You may be able to avoid that penalty with a proper tags database that indicates case-folded sorting by this line:

```
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   2
```

See `:help 'tagbsearch'` for all the details.

Comment: Note when you do this that you need to fold your case to upper case.  I did this backwards and struggled for a while when hitting identifiers (or sections of the tag file) where the underscore was found since it was in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is due to ic! When I removed ic(i.e. set noic), then the speed was drastically improved. g+ctrl-] is as fast as ctrl-] now.

Comment: Really?! It's hard to see why this setting matters. Does this also affect `:tjump`? If you can reliably reproduce this, I'd report this as a bug on the vim_dev mailing list.

Comment: That was not due to incsearch, but ic (ignore case). Really sorry. I have updated it in description and answer. Does ic affect tag search as well apart from normal search? How relevant 'case' is with tags?

Comment: BTW, ic is affecting :tjump as well